# MYSQL subpartition pruning

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a MYSQL table with partition on year and sub-partition on month.

```
CREATE TABLE ptable (
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   name varchar(100),
   purchased DATETIME NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id, purchased)
)

PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(purchased) )
SUBPARTITION BY HASH( MONTH(purchased) )
SUBPARTITIONS 12 (
   PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2011),
   PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2012),
   PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

Most of my queries to this table involves year or month. When I try to query by month, it is not doing pruning properly and scans over all 12 sub-partition of given year.

```
explain partitions

SELECT *
FROM ptable
WHERE purchased BETWEEN '2011-12-01' AND '2011-12-31';
```

My question is there is a way to tell MYSQL to query only specific sub-partition when I know year and month values? Or may be there is better to do this. I am using MYSQL 5.1.

Comment: mysql does it automatically when partition is Made correctly, if i  were you I'd convert the date into int unsigned and use the unix timestamp for partitioning

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-pruning.html says:

> Pruning can also be applied for tables partitioned on a DATE or DATETIME column when the partitioning expression uses the `YEAR()` or `TO_DAYS()` function.

In MySQL 5.5, they added `TO_SECONDS()` to the still-very-short list of functions that MySQL is smart enough to use for partition pruning.

So you should be able to get subpartition pruning to work with:

```
SUBPARTITION BY HASH( TO_DAYS(purchased)/30 )
```

You can still use 12 subpartitions, you'll just find that each month's data won't align with the subpartitions precisely.  But it will prune when it can.

An alternative is that you could add another column to your table, e.g. `purchased_month TINYINT UNSIGNED`, and store the `MONTH(purchased)` value in that column redundantly.  Then use this as your subpartition key:

```
SUBPARTITION BY HASH( purchased_month )
```

Comment: I am stuck with 5.1, so 5.5 is not an option. MYSQL 5.1 did not even allow me to sub-partition as you suggested: SUBPARTITION BY HASH( TO_DAYS(purchased)/30 )

Comment: Yes, you're right, my mistake.  Then all I have to suggest is to store a purchased_month column and subpartition on that.

Answer (score 0):

> Starting in MySQL 5.6.2, SELECT supports explicit partition selection using the PARTITION keyword with a list of partitions or subpartitions

For those who are using newer MySQL, we can use `SELECT * FROM kit.t1 PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...);` to select rows from specified table (sub)partitions